# How to kill a node.js process when it completes the execution or when it goes idle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, process

I am trying to kill a node process after the process completes its execution. The problem here is there is a lot of Database access loop and callbacks. The code execution will be like

```
enter code here
process.on(message, function (err,results){
temp = results.split(":");
for ( i =0;i<temp.length;i++)
{
connection.query(somequery, callback(){
if (results == 1) 
func(results)
else
connection.query(somequery,callback(){
do something
}
}
}
func(results)
{
 connection.query(somequery,callback(){}
}
```

The problem is when i place a process.exit in any of the callback the other query may go incompleted(by the way node works). So, please help me in an approach to solve this problem to kill the process when its execution is complete or when it goes idle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add global counter, in callback to do increase counter by 1, after when callback complete - decrease counter and check if it equal to 0 kill process.

Comment: I can do that but isn't there a possibility of the counter being '0' when the callbacks have completed and about to enter another callback?

Comment: You can, when the counter is being equal to '0', run timer for about a second, and when timer complete, check if counter still '0' then kill process

Comment: the execution of the callbacks are random... hence when i tried using the counter it either escapes to kill the process or kill the process before completing the execution.